# Can I Create a Static-Content Site With WordPress?

Tags: static-website

Hi I'm evaluating wordpress to implement a rather static website (http://www.eddaconsult.se) that now uses static html that I think could be advantageous to do with wordpress since it would make updates and administration easier. Do you agree with me that it's possible to implement these quite simple webpages with wordpress? I started a project to do this at http://eddaconsult.wordpress.com not getting very long since I didn't see how to upload a logo image etc but I'm sure that it can do all or most of what is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course you can recreate that site using WordPress.  You gain the benefit of managing all the pages from the WordPress admin, and gain consistency across all the pages due to the templated nature of WordPress pages.

You can start by finding or creating a very basic theme that mimics the look of the existing site.  Then just copy your content into WordPress Pages (copy and paste.)  You can even make it look like the pages are HTML by adding the .html extension to your permalink structure.  You can redirect traffic to your old pages to the new pages, if the names are different.

So long at the host that hosts www.eddaconsult.se supports PHP 5.2.4 and MySQL 5.0, you can run WordPress without a problem.  Here are the [requirements for WordPress version 3.2](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/).

Without a doubt, you can do this project with WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I consider hosting with wordpress.com ie eddaconsult.wordpress.com, building up the site with their hosting and then redirecting my domain in a way that very little shows that it's actually wordpress powered. I want to avoid installing PHP and MySQL myself and use worpress hosting from wordpress.com which I hope and believe is possible.